# " Error: (Awaiting internal transactions for reason)" when interact with Disperse contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Disperse contract:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xcfa93bc0033049b2e9f6821e102c5f88f2c92301#code

My transaction on blockchain:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xce413bf421becf8fed400cbd41baf725424ff5599abd9f0c268fd4cc100bf37c

Here is my transaction:

```
 const wallets = [ 
    '0x8F9E9f3c63C14374f3F522343523eF2ae8497391',
    '0x7B2419E0Ee0BD034F7Bf24874C12512AcAC6e21C'
    ]
const amounts = wallets.map((wallet) => ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"));
console.log(amounts)
const tx = await connect.disperseEther(wallets, amounts, {
    gasLimit: 1000000,
    gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("10", "gwei"),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you didn't provide any ether when sending the transaction. You have to send 0.2 ether while sending the transaction. I'm assuming you're using ethers.js:

```js
const tx = await connect.disperseEther(wallets, amounts, {
    gasLimit: 1000000,
    gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("10", "gwei"),
    value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.21", "ether") // A little extra, to be safe. The 0.01 extra ether is sent back automatically.
});
```